# Call a function periodically on server in background in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, xmlhttprequest, intervals

I have an API on q server that looks like this:

```
function isLoggedIn(){
   ....
    }
```

This API tell whether a user is logged in or not.

I want to call this API every 15 minutes or within any interval, to check whether the user is authenticated or not on my angular app.

My concern is how to call an API in intervals, and where to write this method.

Comment: simple service. Could start it in run block

Comment: While it is entirely up to your specification/requirement/design, I would suggest you check the login status when you fire any API call, so the client won't hit the server many times if let's say he leave the browser on overnight.

Answer (score 9):

Use setInterval in your main controller.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    // call your service method here
    //isLoggedIn(); in your case
 }, 3000); // This is time period in milliseconds 1000 ms = 1 second.
```

**Or**

use $interval service is injected into your controller function, you can use it to schedule repeated function calls. Here is an example that used the $interval service to schedule a function call every 5 seconds:

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.controller("MyController", function($scope, $interval){

    $interval(isLoggedIn, 5000);

});

function isLoggedIn() {
    console.log("Interval occurred");
    // call your service method here
}
```

Comment: Better use `$inteval` service from Angular, and set it up in `run` method

Comment: Thanks alot. @KashifMustafa

Comment: @NaushadAhmad: welcome, if you got your answer , please mark it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code that I use.

```
app.run( 
function ( $interval, AuthService, $state, $rootScope, $http, $location, $stateParams ) {
$interval( function( event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams ){
    AuthService.keepAlive( $rootScope, $http ).then( function( data ){
        if( data.Result == "false" ){
            AuthService.logout( $http, $rootScope ).then( function( data ){
                $rootScope.returnToState = $location.url();
                //$rootScope.returnToStateParams = toParams.Id;     
                $state.transitionTo("login.signin");
                //event.preventDefault(); 
            });
        }
    });
}, 1000 * 60 );
```

});

its working. I can ping server minute. I am getting response properly.
Small problem when I will remove comment from event.preventDefault I am getting event is not defined.

if possible can you please tell me.

Comment: First check whether your event is null or not, probably its null that's it causing exception.